# bisection_search produce an unexpected None result

Tags: python

I am following an instruction to write a bisection_search:

```
import random
arr = list(range(11))
random.shuffle(arr)
m = 9
#list is a stack in python
def bisection_search(m, arr):
    top_index = len(arr) - 1 # rather than top_index = -1 
    bottom_index = 0
    while  bottom_index <= top_index:
        mid_index = (top_index + bottom_index) // 2
        pivot = arr[mid_index]
        if m == pivot:
            return mid_index
        if m > pivot:
            bottom_index = mid_index + 1
        else:
            top_index = mid_index - 1
    return None

target_index = bisection_search(m, arr)
print(target_index)
## -- End pasted text --
None
```

I used `%paste` of ipython, it return None,
Tried alternatively:

```
In [3]: arr
Out[3]: [4, 10, 7, 3, 0, 1, 9, 6, 2, 5, 8]

In [4]: m
Out[4]: 9

In [5]: bisection_search(m, arr)

In [6]: x = bisection_search(m, arr)

In [7]: x

In [8]: def bisection_search(m, arr):
```

I double-checked the codes and confirmed no bugs in.

How could it produce a None result?

Comment: `random.shuffle(arr)` - you can't binary search a *shuffled* sequence!

Comment: a) as mentioned, binary search can only applied to sorted sequences; b) there is bisect module in Python which does exactly that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: And you are getting because your algo, run on an unordered array, will jump back and forth randomly and the return condition in the loop may not be met, so it returns None

Comment: Could you please collect the comments to answer? @khachik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As others also mentioned, bisect/binary search is only suitable for sorted sequences. You are getting None, because it will randomly jump back and forth based on the condition checking and may not end up hitting the equality check condition and return None as a result
2. Unless you have specific reasons to implement your own bisect, use the one already available https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html.